# (WordPress woocommerce)How to hide cart page checkout button for some user role

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How to hide cart page checkout button for some user role in woocommerce hope there are some codes that I can use for function.php, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample code. Here I remove the proceed to checkout button for the editor role users.

```
function remove_proceed_to_checkout_button() {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $get_user_data = get_userdata( $user_id );
        $role = $get_user_data->roles[0];
        if('editor' == $role ) {
            remove_action('woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'remove_proceed_to_checkout_button');
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: -Question the user role that I want to change is "Student" do I need to put the "Student" Word and change the "editor" sorry I am a nube here.

Comment: Yes, You have to give the user_role that you want to remove. Here I use editor for example. You have to give your required user role slug here. As you are telling Student, so you have to check the user role slug for the Student.
You can check the default user role slugs from here: https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#summary-of-roles

Comment: one thing I try to use the code for the editor but still it can see the chectout botton on the cart page.

Comment: Did you check using it with an editor role? When I test the code on my end, it works properly. I have put the code on my active themes functions.php file. May be this is adding from other plugins. Just check with default theme and only woocommerce plugin activated. If then works then it is conflicting with other codes.